# String to non-array json

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a string that looks like the following:

```
 {
  "results": [
    {
      "address_components": [
        {
          "long_name": "Ireland",
          "short_name": "Ireland",
          "types": [
            "establishment",
            "natural_feature"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "formatted_address": "Ireland",
      "geometry": {
        "bounds": {
          "northeast": {
            "lat": 55.38294149999999,
            "lng": -5.431909999999999
          },
          "southwest": {
            "lat": 51.4475448,
            "lng": -10.4800237
 

         }
            }],
    "status" : "OK"
   }
```

I want to turn this into a json that I can easily traverse. However when I call JSON.parse() on this string I get a json array that is a pain to traverse. I want to be able to extract the lat and lng from northeast without having to loop through the entire array.

Comment: What do you mean by turn it into a JSON? If it's a string, it's already a JSON. If you parse it, you get an object, not a JSON.

Comment: What if there are multiple elements in the `results` array? How will you get all the lat and lng without looping?

Comment: There is one single item in the array. You can just use `[0]`. If there is more than one item, you will have multiple lat/long values anyway, so you'd need iteration of some description.

Comment: If the `result` key is an array I cannot figure another way to do it without a loop

Comment: `object.results[0].geometry.bounds.northeast.lat`

Comment: Thank you VLAZ and Barmar, that solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 var json = `{
    "results": [
        {
            "address_components": [
                {
                    "long_name": "Ireland",
                    "short_name": "Ireland",
                    "types": [
                        "establishment",
                        "natural_feature"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "formatted_address": "Ireland",
            "geometry": {
                "bounds": {
                    "northeast": {
                        "lat": 55.38294149999999,
                        "lng": -5.431909999999999
                    },
                    "southwest": {
                        "lat": 51.4475448,
                         "lng": -10.4800237
                    }
                }
            }
        }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}`;
var data = JSON.parse(json);
var bounds = data.results[0].geometry.bounds;
var bound = bounds.northeast || bounds.southwest;
console.log(bound.lat, bound.lng);
```

If you know northeast is always an option you can simplify this to:

```
console.log(data.results[0].geometry.bounds.northeast);
```

That will give you your lat and lng.